# Group By and Sum result in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hql

```
CREATE TABLE project(
    Id int auto_increment primary key,
    Name char(50) NOT NULL
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE car(
    Id int auto_increment primary key,
    ProjectId int(11) NOT NULL,
    Plate char(10) NOT NULL,
    Latitude varchar(50) DEFAULT '-6.221165',
    Longitude varchar(50) DEFAULT '106.833286',
    LastTemp varchar(20) DEFAULT '0',
    LastSpeed varchar(20) DEFAULT '0',
    LastGap double DEFAULT 0,
    Mileage double DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT fk_car_project FOREIGN KEY(ProjectId)REFERENCES project(Id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE car_log(
    Id int auto_increment primary key,
    CarId int NOT NULL,
    Latitude varchar(50),
    Longitude varchar(50),
    Temp varchar(20),
    Speed varchar(20),
    Gap double DEFAULT 0,
    LogDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT fk_carlog_car FOREIGN KEY(CarId)REFERENCES car(Id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
 )
```

Table car used to save car data and has a foreign key from table project. Table car_log used to save every movement in car (log). I have create object foreach this table.
In this case, I want to display each car summary (sum of Gap per day) in a project.
This is my query when i want to select summary of each car in project 1

```
select CarId, DATE(LogDate) dateOnly, sum(Gap)/1000 KM from car_log where CarId IN (SELECT Id FROM car where ProjectId = 1) group by CarId, dateOnly;
```

But i confuse how to handle this in HQL. I try to create new object to handle this, but confuse to use it. And I want to ask how to solve this,

```
public class CarLogDate {
    private double km;
    private Date date;
    //constructor & setter getter
}
```

Comment: you have car table two times.Can u post proper code

Comment: sorry, thank you for revise. I have edit my code,

Comment: did you tried any query

Comment: yes I did. "select CarId, DATE(LogDate) dateOnly, sum(Gap)/1000 KM from car_log where CarId IN (SELECT Id FROM car where ProjectId = 1) group by CarId, dateOnly;"
but i confuse to convert result to list object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query just replace table name with entity name and table column names with entity properties.

```
List<Object[]> list = 
    select CarId, LogDate dateOnly, sum(Gap)/1000 KM
    from CarLogDate
    where CarId IN
        (SELECT Id FROM car where ProjectId = 1)
    group by CarId, dateOnly;
```

Comment: thank you. It works, i try to write the complete answer below

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Object[]> q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("SELECT O.car.id AS carId, DATE(O.logDate) AS dateOnly, sum(O.gap)/1000 AS Km from CarLog O " +
            "WHERE carId IN (SELECT id FROM Car c where c.project.id = 1) GROUP BY carId, DATE(O.logDate)").list();
for(Object[] a : q)
    System.out.println(a[0]+" "+a[1]+" "+a[2]);
```

Or maybe you can instantiate the object by using Object[] a as parameter.